# php exec work is difference from cli and cron

Tags: php, cron, exec, freebsd

I created a file as test.php and writed some code

```
    $output = [];
    exec('ps aux', $output);
    var_dump($output);
```

When I run it from cli as

> php test.php

I get result is correct such as

> root 60826 0,0  0,0  12568 1612- IJ 21:14 0:00,00 cron: running job (cron)

But if it added to crontab, i writing response to file, can see string as cut off. Example

> root 60826 0,0 0,0 12568 1612- IJ 21:14 0:00,00 cron: running j

my OS FREEBSD

Comment: How exactly do you write the response to a file?

Comment: added to crontab such as  1 * * * * command > file

Comment: nice solution from arrowd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `ps` utility tries to guess terminal size and cut its output according to that. Try adding `-ww` flag to make it not account the terminal size.

Comment: If your writing to the file with [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and have length parameter set, either increase it or remove it completely.

Comment: Flag **-ww** It's great! Thanks a lot